# Force Javascript function call to wait until previous one is finished mvc 4

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to execute two functions in javascript, but the second function have to wait for first function was finished.

View:

```
<button id="DefinirEstab" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="saveContrato(); CountEstab()"> Define
 </button>
```

First function js:

```
function saveContrato() {
$("#formContrato").ajaxSubmit({
    type: "POST",
    url: $("#formContrato").attr("action"),
    clearForm: false,
    success: function () {
        $("#Serie").attr("disabled", true)
    }
});
$("#DefinirEstab").attr("onclick", "CountEstab()");
```

}

Second function js (wait for first was finished):

```
function CountEstab() {

    //Guardar os dados na tabela serviço
    var Serie = $("#Serie").val();
    var NumDoc = $("#NumDoc").val();
    $.getJSON("/Contrato/saveCabecalhoServicos", {
        serie: Serie, numDoc: NumDoc, idForn: window.IdFornecedor, idFilial: e
    });

} else {
    alert("Falta de dados obrigatórios preenchidos!!");
}
```

}

Comment: Call `CountEstab` in the success callback of `saveContrato`, instead of calling at the same time.

Comment: why are you assigning countEstab to the onclick attr instead of passing the function to the click event handler ? $("#DefinirEstab").click(CountEstab)

Answer (score 1):

Call `CountEstab()` inside `success function`.

**html**

```
<button id="DefinirEstab" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Define
</button>
```

**javascript**

```
$('#DefinirEstab').on('click', function() { 
    saveContrato();
    return false;
});   

function saveContrato() {
    $("#formContrato").ajaxSubmit({
        type: "POST",
        url: $("#formContrato").attr("action"),
        clearForm: false,
        success: function () {
            $("#Serie").attr("disabled", true);
            CountEstab();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Does he still need to attatach CountEstab to the click handler for the element if its being called from the success callback?

Comment: No he should remove the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the second function as a callback to the first function.

```
function saveContrato(callback) {
    $("#formContrato").ajaxSubmit({
        type: "POST",
        url: $("#formContrato").attr("action"),
        clearForm: false,
        success: function () {
            $("#Serie").attr("disabled", true)
            callback();
        }
    });
    $("#DefinirEstab").attr("onclick", "CountEstab()");
}

saveContrato(CountEstab)
```

Comment: where i put `saveContrato(CountEstab)` ??